# Что такое "форма прошедшего времени"?

Tags: грамматика

Встретилось задание:

> В каком (в каких) из приведенных предложений глагол употребляется в форме прошедшего времени?
>
> 1. Выходим мы вчера во двор, а там снег!
> 2. Лучше бы ты остался дома!
> 3. Тут она как закричит на всю улицу!
> 4. Чтобы через пять минут вас здесь не было!
> 5. Ни в одном из приведенных предложений нет глагола в форме прошедшего времени.

Тут два глагола (*остался* из 2 и *не было* из 4) употреблены в форме прошедшего времени, но не обозначают его. Верно ли это утверждение?

Comment: Правильный ответ, если верить составителям олимпиады (откуда и взято задание), 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Тут два глагола (остался из 2 и не было из 4) употреблены в форме
>   прошедшего времени со значением других времен. Верно ли это
>   утверждение?

Верно по сути, неверно по формулировке. *"...Употреблены в форме
прошедшего времени со значением других времен"* - вот это никуда не годится, если придерживаться строгих академических понятий. Здесь жуткая путаница между термином "временнАя форма", "грамматическое время" и "наклонение".

У глагола есть ***три формы***, называемых формами настоящего, прошедшего и будущего времени. И есть несколько грамматических категорий, в частности категория грамматического времени и категория наклонения.

Так вот, ***форма*** прошедшего времени (она же "старая форма причастия на -л") используется:
а) для выражения прошедшего времени,
б) для выражения сослагательного наклонения - с частицей "бы" *В последнем случае эта частица "бы" может использоваться самостоятельно   (непосредствественно с глаголом) или в составе союзов "чтобы", "кабы", "дабы", "если бы". При этом еще есть способы выражения семантической сослагательности, не связанные с использованием формы прошедшего времени.*
в) для выражения (семантического) повелительного наклонения ("Пошел!" и т. п.)/

Короче, не надо путать ***форму*** и грамматическую категорию глагола, этой формой выражаемую.

Я бы сказал так.
//-------------
Пункты 2) и 4) имеют в своем составе ***форму*** прошедшего времени, но не выражают прошедшего ***времени***.
//-------------

Поэтому формулировка вопроса некорректна, а при данном ответе - просто неправильна.

Я что-то сильно засомневался в профессионализме автора вопросов...

Comment: В точку! "Не выражают прошедшего времени" - это я и хотел сказать, но, сонный, не смог. Олимпиада "Ломоносов"))

Comment: А все знаете почему? У нас в силу крайней скудости грамматики глагола начисто утратилось понимание разницы между формой и семантическим содержанием. В английском, где глагольных форм всего четыре (с учетом двух причастий) никому и в голову не придет спутать их с временами глагола (в широком смысле, которые Tens). "Времен" этих 24, и столько же в пассиве. Понятно, что  на все времена и наклонения уникальных форм не напасешься. В финском, правда, если не соврали, полторы дюжины наклонений - и на каждое форма отдельная. Так что мы еще в хорошем положении.

Answer (score 2):

Да, вроде бы  верно. №2 - это сослагательное наклонение, №4 - повелительное наклонение,  а прошедшее время имеют только глаголы в изъявительном наклонении.